# Multiple HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING in one server block

Tags: nginx, passenger

As the title says, I need to have two `HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING` environment variables in a server block in Nginx.

Simply specifying twice the config doesn't work since the second one overwrites the first.

This is what I have (doesn't work):

```
server {
  listen   80;

  root /var/www/mysite/public;
  server_name www.mysite.com;

  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  passenger_env_var HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING /var/www/mysite/myfolder/=/loc/;
  passenger_env_var HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING /var/www/mysite/myotherfolder/=/loc2/;
  passenger_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

  location /loc {
    root /var/www/mysite/myfolder;
    internal;
  }

  location /loc2 {
    root /var/www/mysite/myfolder;
    internal;
  }

}
```

Everything works fine with just one `HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING` but I am unable to specify more than one. I've tried specifying the multiple values by separating them with a comma like the following:

```
passenger_env_var HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING /var/www/mysite/myfolder/=/loc/,/var/www/mysite/myotherfolder/=/loc2/;
```

but that didn't work.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2021/01:**

Per the comments, this is now supported by Rack: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1387#issuecomment-573355784

**Original Answer:**

Based on the current implementation of the rack gem, this isn't possible. This is the code in [rack 2.0.1 (lib/rack/sendfile.rb)](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/sendfile.rb#L152-L154)

```
def map_accel_path(env, path)
  if mapping = @mappings.find { |internal,_| internal =~ path }
    path.sub(*mapping)
  elsif mapping = env['HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING']
    internal, external = mapping.split('=', 2).map(&:strip)
    path.sub(/^#{internal}/i, external)
  end
end
```

As you can see this code only looks for the first '=' and assumes everything before it is the internal path and everything after is the external path.

Comment: Support for multiple mappings was [recently added to Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1187) but is not yet part of a release.

Comment: Multiple mappings seem to [have been released](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1387#issuecomment-573355784) as part of Rack 2.1.0 in January 2020 ([Changelog](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#210---2020-01-10))